# Open an Outlook within angular controller

Tags: angularjs, outlook

This is working:

**Html**

```
<a href="mailto:?subject={{vm.property.address.streetNumber}}, {{vm.property.address.streetName}} {{vm.cityName}} {{vm.stateName}}%20IPL%20#%20{{vm.property.id}}&body={{comment.note}}">@L("CsEmail")</a>
```

This is not working:

```
<a ng-href="{{vm.email}}" ng-click="vm.composeEmail(comment)">@L("CsEmail")</a>
```

**js**

```
vm.composeEmail = function (data) {
vm.email = "mailto:?subject={{vm.property.address.streetNumber}}, {{vm.property.address.streetName}} {{vm.cityName}} {{vm.stateName}}%20IPL%20#%20{{vm.property.id}}&body={{data.note}}";

    // I need to save this here

                };
```

Q : I need to save the data after sending the email.Hence I cannot use the first option.But 2nd option is not working.That means it is not opening the outlook. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use this from an angular controller:

```
vm.composeEmail = function (data) {
    var email = "mailto:...";
    //save here
    $window.location.href = email;
};
```

This way you can save whatever needs to be saved, and then open the mail client from the controller. The html will look something like this:

```
<a ng-href="" ng-click="vm.composeEmail(comment)">@L("CsEmail")</a>
```

You also need to break up your 'mailto' string, as thegio suggests.

Answer (score 1):

why not directly using the scope vars, like that:

```
vm.email = "mailto:?subject=" + vm.property.address.streetNumber + ", " + vm.property.address.streetName + " " + vm.cityName + " " + vm.stateName + " " + "IPL# " + vm.property.id + "&body=" + data.note;
```

did you tried to add target="_blank":

```
<a ng-href="{{vm.email}}" ng-click="vm.composeEmail(comment)" target="_blank">@L("CsEmail")</a>
```

Comment: As I mentioned above then it has not being opened the outlook.Do you know why ? Thanks.

Comment: is a bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6967 try with target _blank

Comment: or look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925326/angularjs-mailto-not-sending-emails

Comment: Thanks for the braking the string +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a better solution:

```
   <div ng-app="myApp"> 
     <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <a href="mailto:{{email}}"><span>Email {{email}}</span></a> 
    </div> 
  </div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
var MyCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.email = 'bob@bob.com';
    $scope.name = "Bob";
    $scope.cc = "test@test.com";
    $scope.subject = "this is the subject";
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: not necessary, this is just and example, you can concatenate them in one long string.

Comment: Thanks for the support +1. It seems more work for me :(  @fikkatra solution is working.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `$window.open('mailto:etc');` inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

inside "composeemail" function open a new window

```
$window.location.href = 'mailto:etc'
```

and remove the value inside `ng-href`